# Getting deployment error HRESULT: 0x80070002 System cannot find the file specified when adding a file to the solution in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, xsd, hresult

I added a Schema.xml file to a list instance in my solution. When I attempt to deploy the solution, it throws an exception saying that it cannot find the specified file HRESULT 0x80070002. If I remove the Schema.xml, it deploys fine.

I have checked the Elements.xml to make sure the CustomSchema attribute is correct, which it is.

I have checked the SharePointProjectItem.spdata file to make sure it is referencing the file correctly, which it is.

The Schema.xml deployment type is specified as ElementFile.

I have deleted the bin and obj folders as well as retracted, cleaned, and reloaded the project. Issue still exists.

Any ideas as to where the deployment step is looking for this file and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find an answer if so could you share it  ?